# linking UIProgressView to show download progress using Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage, uiprogressview

i am trying to show progress view of the file that i am download when i printed the progress it is right but when i implement it on the progress view it is completely wrong it goes to 3000% here is my code. i am using MHRadialProgressView

```
downloadTask.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) -> Void in
    // Download reported progress

    let percentComplete = 100 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount) / Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)
    print("percentComplete")
    self.progressView.moveNext(currentprogress as NSNumber!)

    // Update the progress indicator
}
```

when i used MBProgressHUD here is the code for it

```
  downloadTask.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) -> Void in
                // Download reported progress    
                let percentComplete = 100 * Float(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
                    / Float(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)

            let hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: (self.navigationController?.view)!, animated: true)
            // Set the determinate mode to show task progress.
            hud.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.determinate

            hud.label.text = NSLocalizedString("Loading...", comment: "HUD loading title")
            // Set up NSProgress
            let progressObject = Progress(totalUnitCount: 100)
            hud.progressObject = progressObject
            // Configure a cancel button.


            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async(execute: {() -> Void in
                // Do something useful in the background and update the HUD periodically.

                while progressObject.fractionCompleted < 1.0 {

                    progressObject.becomeCurrent(withPendingUnitCount: 1)
                    progressObject.resignCurrent()
                    usleep(useconds_t(percentComplete))
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                    hud.hide(animated: true)
                })
            })
        }
```

i am getting this error 
nanfatal error: Float value cannot be converted to UInt32 because it is either infinite or NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few recommendations:

- Don't use this library (it hasn't been updated since 2014), use [`MBProgressHUD`](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD), which allows you to [set a progress object and forget about it](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD#usage).
- If you still want to use the original library, make sure to read the documentation--it says, "or unordered progres [sic] (often by steps associated wtih [sic] user action), you can increase the progress by value". This means you need to diff the previous progress with the current progress and increment or decrement it yourself.

Comment: please check the code above when i used MBProgressHUD i am getting this error.    nanfatal error: Float value cannot be converted to UInt32 because it is either infinite or NaN

Comment: Can you explain why you don't just do: `hud.progressObject = snapshot.progress`? Everything else seems convoluted and unnecessary.